# Kohana: Auth hash key issue in Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, authentication, hash, kohana

Kohana: When i am using Auth module, getting below mentioned error: 
A valid hash key must be set in your auth config.

Code which is being called is:

```
public function hash($str) 
{       
if ( ! $this->_config['hash_method'])           return $str;        
if ( ! $this->_config['hash_key'])          
throw new Kohana_Exception('A valid hash key must be set in your auth config.');        
return hash_hmac($this->_config['hash_method'], $str, $this->_config['hash_key']);
}
```

here i can see that hash_key is not coming properly, when i remove this check everything works fine. Can you please help understand what is the issue?

I am using Auth::instance()->login("userid", "password");

Comment: Did you set a hash key in your config like it says?

Comment: How can we set the hash key, Can you please guide me in right direction? Also i am using Kohana active record instead of ORM, so do how do i need to set roles with user details? any link which can guide in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your auth config file (if you haven't got one, put it here `./application/config/auth.php`), you need to defined a hash key.  Use a random string.  Example:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array(

    'driver'       => 'ORM',
   'hash_method'  => 'sha256',

    // This is the important line
    'hash_key'     => 'seilrrskj34sljusd',
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
    'users' => array()

);
```